# jQuery - How to order timing of dragging and clicking events, sharing the same UI element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, settimeout, draggable

I have a horizontal scroll of movies. User should be able to **drag** the element to scroll horizontally as well as **click** on each movie to open a video player.

[image]

The problem is, both dragging and clicking listen to the same event listeners:
`mouse down` `mouse up` (and `mouse move` for dragging)

**I want to achieve this:**

1. When user clicks a movie quickly (mouse down and up within 1 second), it is determined as a click and click callback is fired.
2. When user drags (mouse down, then hold the mouse for more than 1 second, then proceed to drag), click callback is cancelled and drag callback is fired.

My code (bellow) makes the scroll behave like this, **which I don't want**:

1. After user finishes dragging the scroll, click event is fired making a movie open.

**Html**

```
<ul class="scroll">
    <li><a href="linkToMovie"></a></li>
    <li><a href="linkToMovie"></a></li>
<ul>
```

**JS**

```
var $scroll = (".scroll");
    var $movie = $scroll.children($("movie")

    $scroll.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).on("mousemove", function() {
            //drag horizontally
        });
    });
    $scroll.on("mouseup", function(){
        //...
    }); 

    $movie.on("click", function(){
        //open movie
    })
```

Comment: You can set a flag on mouse down, and unset it when dragging/mouseup. On mouse up, check the flag and decide whether or not to do the click behavior on.

Comment: @eran The problem is, click event is basically mouse down and mouse up event. When a user clicks on a movie, the event listens to: click, mouse down, mouse up events. Even 'e.preventDefault()' can't stop a click from accessing all those events.

Comment: @eran if on mouse up I decide to not do click behavior, then user will never be able to click on a movie.

Comment: That's the whole point. You decide not to do it when the mouse is moved thus the gesture is interpreted as dragging. You never do anything onclick, you only do stuff on mouse up based on the flag you set.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var drag = false;
var hold = false;

var $scroll = (".scroll");
var $movie = $scroll.children($("movie")

$scroll.on("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hold = e.target;
    $(this).on("mousemove", function() {
        drag = true;
    });
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    if(!drag && $(hold).is(e.target)){
        //open movie
    }
    hold = false;
    drag = false;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Your code means, dragging goes on, until a movie is clicked.

Comment: Correct. Updated my answer, so it should work now. Click event is exactly same with mouseup/mousedown event on the same element